# SQL/PHP updates multiple rows when client modifies javascript function parameter for two buttons to be the same

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, mysqli

I am trying to create a vote up functionality where a user can view many comments can and vote each of them. Each vote up button looks like this,

```
<input type="button" value="UpVote93" id="upvote_55" onclick="upvote('commendID1')">
<input type="button" value="UpVote42" id="upvote_56" onclick="upvote('commendID2')">
```

The upvote(param) function is an ajax call like this,

```
function upvote(x) {
     $.ajax({
          url: 'dbHandler.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
               "action": 'UPVOTE_COMMENT',
               "unique_answer_id": x
           },
           success: function(data){ 
                 alert(1);
            },
            failure: function(data){ 
                 alert(0);
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                 alert(2);  
            }
      });
}
```

and the php update statement looks like this,

```
$query = $conn->query("UPDATE answers SET vote_count = vote_count+1 WHERE commentID='$commentID' LIMIT 1>
```

The problem is that, the user can change the second button upvote parameter to "commentID1". Now, when he clicks the second button, two rows are updated in the the mysql database for the both comments, i.e. commentID1 and commentID2.

I tried the same thing on voting tutorial sites and was able replicated the issue. However, when I tired on sites like Quora, the bug was not there. What is the best approach for this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning your inputs into html arrays. PHP is good at reading those. Something like:

```
<input name="MyArray[]" /> 
<input name="MyArray[]" />
```

Then you can read the input as an array and process it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to users being able to vote for a comment more than once?

1. If your users have to be logged in, then you can easily store their user id next to the vote in the database to make sure they only vote once per comment.
2. If login is not required, you can either store their IP address in the DB, or save it in their session (or possibly a cookie) that they have already voted.